# How can i add three objects into one in mutableArray in iphone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

```
NSMutableArray * mutableArra = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[mutableArra addObjectsFromArray:myArray];
NSLog(@"=====mutable aarrya ====::%@",mutableArra);
```

This is the result from the previous code:

> 01,12,2012

How can I add these three objects into one like the following?

> 01-12-2012

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please, when you create a new question try to explain your problem first. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how do you want to "add" those poor objects to one another, but if you want them to be concatenated as a string, try:

```
NSString *result = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@"-"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for dates, I would recommend looking into NSDate which will do the formatting for you.